# Dataloader Extract CLI Process.bat Error

Tags: data-loader, error

I am trying to do an extract via the CLI of dataloader and getting an error when I run my process.bat.

Here is error message when running process.bat on csvAccountExtractProcess in the process-conf file:

C:\dataloader\bin>process.bat C:\dataloader\retest\conf\process-conf.xml csvAccountExtractProcess

0 [main] INFO com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessConfig  - Loading process
 configuration from config file: C:\dataloader\retest\conf\process-conf.xml\proc
ess-conf.xml
31 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  -
Loading XML bean definitions from file [C:\dataloader\retest\conf\process-conf.x
ml\process-conf.xml]
34 [main] ERROR com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessConfig  - Error loading
 process: csvAccountExtractProcess configuration from config file: C:\dataloader
\retest\conf\process-conf.xml\process-conf.xml
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException pars
ing XML document from file [C:\dataloader\retest\conf\process-conf.xml\process-c
onf.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dataloader\retes
t\conf\process-conf.xml\process-conf.xml (The system cannot find the path specif
ied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dataloader\retest\conf\process-conf.xml\proces
s-conf.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.getInputStream(FileSys
temResource.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:167)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:148)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.(XmlBeanFa
ctory.java:68)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.(XmlBeanFa
ctory.java:56)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessConfig.getBeanFactory(Proces
sConfig.java:79)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessConfig.getProcessInstance(Pr
ocessConfig.java:68)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.getInstance(ProcessRu
nner.java:260)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.getInstance(ProcessRu
nner.java:246)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.main(ProcessRunner.ja
va:219)
42 [main] FATAL com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner  - Failed to cre
ate process
com.salesforce.dataloader.exception.ProcessInitializationException: Error loadin
g process: csvAccountExtractProcess configuration from config file: C:\dataloade
r\retest\conf\process-conf.xml\process-conf.xml
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessConfig.getProcessInstance(Pr
ocessConfig.java:72)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.getInstance(ProcessRu
nner.java:260)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.getInstance(ProcessRu
nner.java:246)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.main(ProcessRunner.ja
va:219)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOExc
eption parsing XML document from file [C:\dataloader\retest\conf\process-conf.xm
l\process-conf.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\datal
oader\retest\conf\process-conf.xml\process-conf.xml (The system cannot find the
path specified)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:148)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.(XmlBeanFa
ctory.java:68)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.(XmlBeanFa
ctory.java:56)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessConfig.getBeanFactory(Proces
sConfig.java:79)
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessConfig.getProcessInstance(Pr
ocessConfig.java:68)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dataloader\retest\conf\process-conf
.xml\process-conf.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.getInputStream(FileSys
temResource.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBea
nDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:167)
        ... 8 more
C:\dataloader\bin>

Below is my process-conf file:
[image]

SOQL that got cut off:
select id, name, owner.termination_date__c, owner.profile.name, owner.name, owner.managerid, owner.userrole.name from account where owner.termination_date__c <= today and owner.userrole.name like 'wws%' and owner.isactive = false

Can you please advise as to what I need to fix in order to properly extract?  If you need any additional info let me know

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it can't find certain files - so I would check a couple of things - do all the files exist at the locations specified, is the path set correctly in the .bat file to the process conf file, and does accountextract.csv already exist (dataloader can be funny about writing to files if they don't exist)

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC
I have confirmed that all the files I referenced in the process-conf are in the correct locations and the accountextract.csv is there as well.  I believe that I set the path correctly for the .bat file (went into the PATH via GUI and added C:\dataloader\bin).

Are there other files that are required to be in the conf folder in order to properly extract that I might be missing?  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I think I'd need to try the files out on my machine to see if I can see the issue...can you zip them up and send me a link?